# Is it possible to transclude the tab content?

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

Is it possible to create a tab with either HTML content or move the element directly to the content?

Here is what I am trying to do, ultimately, i want to just move existing element(s) inside the tab content:

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <tabset ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="tabs">
      <tab class="tab" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" sortable-tab heading="{{tab.title}}">{{tab.content}}</tab>
    </tabset>

    <button type="button" ng-click="addSimple()">Add simple</button>
    <button type="button" ng-click="addHtml()">Add html</button>
    <button type="button" ng-click="addElement()">Add element</button>
    <button type="button" ng-click="removeTab()">Remove tab</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.sortable']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var count = 0;
  $scope.sortableOptions = {
    distance: 10,
    axis: 'x',
    update: function(event, ui) {
     // $scope.activeTab = ui.item.sortable.dropindex;
    }
  };
  $scope.tabs = [
    {title:'Test', content:'hello world'},
  ];
  $scope.addSimple = function() {
    count++;
    var newTab = {title: 'New tab ' + count, content: 'Works'};
    $scope.tabs.push(newTab);
  }
  $scope.addHtml = function() {
    count++;
    var newTab = {title: 'New tab ' + count, content: '<div>Broken</div>'};
    $scope.tabs.push(newTab);
  }
  $scope.addElement = function() {
    count++;
    var newTab = {title: 'New tab ' + count, content: angular.element('<div>Broken</div>')};
    $scope.tabs.push(newTab);
  }
  $scope.removeTab = function() {
    $scope.tabs.pop();
  }
});
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tYmoWE?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

It's already transcluded, but if you want to inject HTML, you'll have to use ngBindHtml (requires ngSanitize as a dependency).

## [Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sNOTdo?p=preview)

Add angular-sanitize.js make sure ngSanitize is added as a dependency:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.sortable', 'ngSanitize']);
```

Change your markup to add ng-bind-html:

```
<tab class="tab" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" sortable-tab heading="{{tab.title}}">
  <div ng-bind-html="tab.content"></div>
</tab>
```

Then you can pass html directly:

```
{title: 'New tab ' + count, content: '<strong>Works with <span class="red">ngBindHtml</span></strong>'}
```

Or, using the angular.element html() method to grab the element object's html:

```
{title: 'New tab ' + count, content: angular.element('<div>Broken</div>').html()}
```

Comment: How about the example in my tab3? What If i want to simply move an existing element inside the tab?

Comment: Updated the Plunker.  The  angular.element is the object wrapper, so just  use the html() method to grab its html.

Comment: So there is no way to move existing DOM element? Because the element is a custom object that I created and it has its own objects, events, etc bind to it, so I can't just use `html()`.

I just simplified the example in the Plunker, but ultimately i try to `MOVE` the element into the content.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by MOVE.  Do you mean you have a directive that you want to inject?

Comment: See my updated Plunker. I've just created a dummy element and bind some event and data to it, using `html()` would lost all of that for example.

Comment: Okay, your example didn't help.  What is it that you want to accomplish?  Your updated Plunkr is using AngularJS and jQuery mixed together in a way that you simply wouldn't do in an Angular app.  There might be an "angular" way to accomplish what you want to, but I don't know what you want and I don't see any value in giving you some hack answer that is at its core contrary to the basic tenets of building Angular apps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79030/discussion-between-codenamezero-and-jme11).